# How to update a column with incrementally sequenced values that change depending on other column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sequence, row-number

I am trying to update a column in a table so that the Index column (which is currently arbitrary numbers) is renumbered sequentially starting at 1000 with increments of 10, and this sequence restarts every time the Group changes.

I have tried ROWNUMBER() with PARTITION and trying to define a SEQUENCE, but I can't seem to get the result I'm looking for.

Table 1

```
ID    Group    Index
1         A       1
2         A       2
3         B       3
4         B       4
5         B       5
6         C       6
7         D       7
```

What I want:
Table 1

```
ID    Group       Index
1         A       1000
2         A       1010
3         B       1000
4         B       1010
5         B       1020
6         C       1000
7         D       1000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` with some arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       990 + 10 * row_number() over (partition by group order by id) as index
from t;
```

Note that `group` and `index` are SQL reserved words, so they are really bad column names.

Comment: @Chelsea Note that : The above formula is calculated based on Operator Precedence look ....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql